# Django template outliner

Tags: django, templates, inheritance, graph, django-templates

I'm trying to obtain a visual representation of the templates of a Django project, as a hierarchy.

The main idea is to get a list of template names as the default template loading machinery would return (ie honoring `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`, etc.) and then parsing the templates looking for `{% block %}` and {% extends %} tags, in order to create a tree structure. Finally use grapviz for the visualization.

I'm not sure if it's a viable approach. But just to start, how can I load the templates the way I described?

Or maybe, does something similar already exist?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, templates are looked up by names online, there is no root entry for every template that might be used.

Thus if you want to grep all used templates in a project, you need to scan every place that loaders in TEMPLATE_LOADERS might check, to generate possible entries for later bottom-to-up checking. This would be hard, some backends of loaders might even does not allow fetch-by-directory operation.
Or you could parse views and urls files inside INSTALLED_APPS to grep template names, but this only works w/ hard-coded name of template and even more difficult.
Also, there might be templates loaded from hard-coded string...

For a given template name, its easier to load the template and check nodes inside it, just as your idea. You could check `django.template.base` to know how it works.

Furthermore, you could take advantage of django-debug-toolbar to show the templates used for a request. And, IMO, keeping template structure flat, simple and thus determined, is easier to achieve.

Comment: I understand it's not an easy task, even because templates can be included in other templates by conditions, which can't be handled because are not known beforehand.