# Get inherited templates in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any way to get list of all templates inherited from base template?
For example:
We have base template file:

```
base.html
```

and we have templates inherited from base

```
inherited0.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
inherited1.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
inherited2.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Do we have any not documented capabilities for fetching list of this templates?

Comment: If you want some variable to show up on all templates, use a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).

Comment: so you want that base knows each template that extends it, or you want to fetch a list of all the extended templates for each template you have?

Comment: base knows each template that extends it

Comment: I guess that you will have to write your own script which will go through all templates and search for `extends` tag. Should not be that difficult, even with recursive inheritance.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149713/django-template-outliner

Answer (score 1):

You can use a find and grep command from your base folder:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print | xargs grep "extends 'base.html'"
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to method for doing  this is missing.
So the solution of this problem is searching in templates files string like "{% extends 'base.html' %}".